# Error al usar el plugin "Export Telegram Sticker" de Synfig Studio en Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, telegram-bot

Cuando trato de exportar una animacion hecha me devuelve este error

```
import lottie
AttributeError: 'module' has no attribute 'auto'
```

Aun no pude resolverlo pero al tratar de ejecutar

```
lottie_convert.py input_file.gif output_file.json --bmp-mode trace
```

me sale este error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/lottie_convert.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('lottie==0.6.3+src', 'lottie_convert.py')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 576, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 589, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 778, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'lottie==0.6.3+src' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: estás en Python?

Comment: Si, es un plugin para Synfig 
https://gitlab.com/mattia.basaglia/python-lottie
https://pypi.org/project/lottie/